# How can I load my own 404 page

Tags: http-status-code-404

I am trying to load my own 404 page when failing to get a page because of unable to connect error.

I am currently trying listening for onComplete() events. Then I try and do another Browser.loadURL().

Comment: What kind of system is this for? If you can't connect to an HTTP server, you won't get a 404 response from it, you will get a socket error instead. As for the content of a 404 response, that is up to the server to decide. So unless you are writing your own server, or your hosting provider offers an option for custom 404 pages, you won't be able to customize the 404 response.

Comment: What do you use to create the website?